# Error when linking for android. Error: cannot find -lmysqlcppconn & error: undefined reference to 'sql::mysql::get_driver_instance()

Tags: c++, mysql, linker-errors, scons, godot

I have used a custom MySQL module and I am trying to compile for android.
But I will encounter this error whenever trying to compile.

Steps:
Execute scons platform=android target=release android_arch=armv7

I tried to google this error and from what I have understood, I think that I am required to link the MySQL library. But I am unsure of how do I do that.
Thank you!

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVJ1n.png)

Comment: Almost always better to post the text instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

use -lmysqlcppconn8 not -lmysqlcppconn